# Can't add item to combobox (form control) in vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have several ComboBoxes (form control) on `sheet1`. I would like to loop through and populate them. Nothing happens, no error or no items in the list of each ComboBox. I use this code:

```
Sub cmbBox()
    Dim ctrl As Shape
    For Each ctrl In Sheet1.Shapes
        If ctrl.Type = msoOLEControlObject Then
            ctrl.AddItem "Done"
            ctrl.AddItem "Not Done"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly loop through the DropDowns (this is how Form Control "ComboBoxes" are called) instead of looping all `Shapes` …

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub PopulateCombos()
    Dim dd As DropDown
    For Each dd In Sheet1.DropDowns
        dd.AddItem "Done"
        dd.AddItem "Not Done"
    Next dd
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! That helped me a lot!